# Update Raspberry Pi Flash with change of SD Card

Tags: pi-4, update, firmware, bootloader

I know that the firmware on the Raspberry Pi 4 is automatically updated trough the package manager. If I install a new version of  `rpi-eprom` (or is it another package?) trough `apt upgrade` the boot-flash is automatically updated.

What happens now if I insert the SD card with the updated package into another Pi (same type)? Does it auto-update during boot or do I have to redo the upgrade? The problem is that a) the Pi I'm going to insert this card into does not have an internet connection. And b) even if it had, an upgrade wouldn't do anything, since obviously the package version will stay current.

Comment: How firmware is updated depends upon which model of the Raspberry Pi you have. Please edit your question to let us know which RPi you're asking about. For example, RPi 4 has some of its firmware in EEPROM - not on SD card.

Comment: @Seamus : This is particularly about the Pi4. Just _because_ it has some of the firmware in the EEPROM, I'm asking how it gets updated when the firmware on the SD card is newer than the one in EEPROM

Comment: That's much more clear, thanks - it's a good question now. I've never checked this, and can't research it now, but I *suspect* that your RPi 4's EEPROM will remain in its original state until you perform a `update` and `full-upgrade`. I also suspect the answer may be in [this document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md), or in [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md). You've likely read at least one of these, but the EEPROM version can be obtained through the command line IIRC.

Comment: The documents you linked to seem to give most of the answer. It seems that even if the update doesn't happen automatically, it can be performed also without an internet connection. Unfortunately, I cannot test this, as my second Pi is currently out of reach (as in: a 1000km + possible quarantine away)